# Change value of each item of string inside the list inside the list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a class Dad which has list of kids:

```
public class Dad
{
    public List<Kid> kids = new List<Kid>();;
}
```

Each of those kids has a toy:

```
public class Kid
{
    public List<string> Toys = new List<string>();
}
```

and as a sample I have collection of dads:

```
Dad d1 = new Dad();
Kid k1 = new Kid();
k1.Toys.Add("toy1");
k1.Toys.Add("toy2");
d1.Kids.Add(k1);
List<Dad> dads = new List<Dad> { d1 };
```

I am trying to understand how to perform LINQ of List of Dads to change each kid's toy name to upper case.

Something like:

```
var dadsWithKidsWithChangeToysName = dads.Select(dad => dad.Kids.Select(kid => kid.Toys.ForEach(toy => toy.ToUpper())));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is for query, It is not for modification. **You shouldn't use it for modification**. Instead use a simple iteration (foreach/for) etc.

You can use LINQ to create a new `List` of `Dad` based on your existing list like:

```
var modifiedDads = dads.Select(d => new Dad()
{
    Kids = d.Kids.Select
        (
            k => new Kid()
            {
                Toys = k.Toys.Select(t => t != null ? t.ToUpper() : t).ToList()
            }
        ).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your classes have a constructor accepting an IEnumerable, you could get it like so :

```
    public class Dad
    {
        public List<Kid> kids = new List<Kid>();

        public Dad(IEnumerable<Kid> kids)
        {
            this.kids = kids.ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Kid
    {
        public List<string> Toys = new List<string>();

        public Kid(IEnumerable<string> toys)
        {
            Toys = toys.ToList();
        }
    }

    var dads = new List<Dad> {
        new Dad(new [] { new Kid(new [] { "a", "b" }) }),
        new Dad(new [] { new Kid(new [] { "c", "d" }) }),
    };

    var dadsWithKidsWithChangeToysName = dads.Select(d => new Dad(d.kids.Select(k => new Kid(k.Toys.Select(t => t.ToUpper())))));
```